# Edit Google Chrome preferences offline

Tags: google-chrome

Is there an offline editor for the Chrome `Preferences` file? The file is stored at the location `<USER>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.

The file is standard ASCII but not in a format like XML, possibly a proprietary Google format. Manually editing this dense format in Notepad looks risky (though I will back up my copy before editing). My own `Preferences` file contains over 129,000 characters and starts like this:

`{"account_id_migration_state":2,"account_tracker_service_last_update":"13126887370971000","apps":{"shortcuts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a json file, a text data format which share similarities with xml but with a different syntax.
It's safe to edit with a text editor, as you said you should do a backup beforehand.

You can find [json formatters](https://www.google.com/search?q=json%20formatter) on the internet to make the file more readable, i.e. it will indent the file. But I don't know if they will behave nicely with a large json like that.

Comment: Well spotted, turned out to be JSON format. I've downloaded the `JSONViewer plugin` for Notepad++ (https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/?source=typ_redirect). After restarting Notepad++, the command Plugins > JSON Viewer > Format JSON works as expected.